# Rails app: @javascript Selenium Cucumber/Capybara tests fail with object Undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I recently upgraded my Mac from Sierra to High Sierra. A rails app I work on that has Cucumber tests now fails with a weird error:

Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidArgumentError)

I have tried running these tests on Firefox 56.0.2 (which worked for weeks just fine before the upgrade) and now 57.0.1.

I have seen this error mentioned in a number of places on the web but apparently only for older versions of geckodriver. I am running version 0.19.1. I have verified as best I can that there are no old geckodriver versions sitting around.

The error crops up when trying to run the "fill_in" command of capybara. I was originally running selenium_webdriver 3.4.4 but have also tried 3.6.0 and 3.8.0 (latest version).

The confusing thing is that my officemates have also upgraded to High Sierra, run the same Firefox versions I have tested, use selenium 3.4.4, and the same geckodriver version I am. Their tests pass. So I'm wondering if anyone knows what OTHER setting/app would be involved in this process that could be different between my machine and my officemates. Thanks for any input.

Comment: I tested updates of the capybara gem on the project with no change in behavior. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the ruby version (2.1.10) for rvm. I've rebuilt all the gemsets chained to 2.1.10 installtion for all projects. Finally I've run the tests on all those web applications that use different versions of capybara. All of the apps fail in the same fashion with the above error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been found. I had an executable file called geckodriver.sav sitting in /usr/local/bin. It was an older version of geckodriver. In /usr/local/bin there is a link to the up to date geckodriver in my homebrew cellar. If you look at the selenium source code it chooses "geckodriver*" as the file to launch. Apparently this .sav file was being preferred over the link (maybe arbitrarily based on order files are discovered). Moved the .sav files out of /usr/local/bin and my tests are now all passing.

Comment: I reported the behavior of selenium driver to accept geckodriver* as an input and they have since fixed this behavior. See https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5240